# How to replace doubles with BigDecimal for monies in java

Tags: java, currency, bigdecimal

I am doing a college assignment where I have used doubles for money. I know it is not advisable to use doubles for monetary values so I am wondering how I can replace my existing code that has doubles with BigDecimal.

Since it is a college assignment, I didn't want direct help on my code and didn't want to post it here either, so I have created the following code to which I would appreciate direct replies, i.e. change the code I am providing so that I can understand what's going on.

I am wondering how BigDecimal can be multiplied/divided/added/subtracted with an int or a double or if that isn't even a possiblity.

There are other topics covering BigDecimal usage but they don't cover my specific question, however, I apologize if I have overlooked a post where it has already been answered.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

class example {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    NumberFormat fm = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    System.out.println("Enter the first amount:");
    double money1 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the second amount:");
    double money2 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the third amount:");
    double money3 = in.nextDouble();

    double tax = 0.2;
    double totalmoney = money1 + money2 + money3;
    double moneytax = (totalmoney)*tax;


    System.out.println("Your money added together is: " + fm.format(totalmoney));
    System.out.println("Tax on your money is: " + fm.format(moneytax));
    System.out.println("Your money after tax deduction is: " + fm.format((totalmoney-moneytax)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to BigDecimal might be to do all calculations in cents, using longs, and just insert the decimal point right at the end.

Comment: I have tried that with Integer.toString etc, adding a decimal by moving it back two places however I am not sure how to calculate it by multiplying to 20% of tax, if you can help me with that, that'd be great.

Comment: 20% is one fifth.  Tax is `amount / 5`.  Take home is `(4 * amount) / 5` with a check for rounding errors.

Comment: Sorry for my noob questions, but wouldn't calculating tax for, say, 4049 cents result in a decimal point and hence inaccurate calculation since an int would ignore anything that comes after the decimal? Or would NumberFormat fix that?

Comment: The reason I am accepting this answer is because that is what they are asking for in the assignment. Not really sure how I will complete this task though.

Comment: The question should give you rounding rules to tell you want to do with the odd fractions of a cent.  Ask your instructor if the question is not clear on what to do in this case.  You could amend things to work in units of 0.1 cent and then do a final rounding at the end of the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid using double, you need to not use it from the start.

```
BigDecimal money1 = new BigDecimal(in.nextLine());
```

You should be able to see that the result is exactly the same after rounding.

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimals are immutable, but you can create new ones with specific calls:

```
BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal("2.00");
BigDecimal four = new BigDecimal("4.00");

BigDecimal result = four.divide(two);
```

You'll probably also want to look at the scale() methods.